# How to draw two tangentlines to the circle in the complex plane

Tags: graphics, complex, geometry

From the origin(0,0) of the complex plane, draw two tangent lines to the circle  (see plot (p1)).

The absolute value of a complex number is a vector from origin to complex number in complex plane.

`p1 = ComplexContourPlot[Abs[z - 6*I] == 3,  {z, -10 - 10*I, 10 + 10*I}, GridLines -> Automatic,  PlotLabel -> Abs[z - 6*I] == 3]`

I do want also show the two axis (Real and Imaginair) in the ComplexContourPlot, but how?

Two values are calculated by :
`Reduce[{Abs[z - 6*I] == 3, Arg[z] > 0}, z]`

Solution: i do have two points, then show this line is a tangent of the circle?
Perhaps there is formula for this ? ..  or solving with circle math

Note: is there a better approach? using the geometric packages for this.

Comment: Have you seen `Axes -> True` and `AxesStyle -> ...`?

Comment: Technically, `Reduce[{Abs[z - 6*I] == 3, Arg[z] > 0}, z]` returns infinitely many points (all the points on the circle), with two points on the diameter `Im[z] == 6` distinguished. The line through those two points is obviously not tangent to the circle, nor are the lines from the origin through each point. Your reduce command should include a condition of tangency...

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks. There are no tangent line(s) from the origin to the diameter of the circle to draw.

Comment: Exactly my point. (And you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you want to compute tangency, but here's a way that works for the circle:

```
With[{
  center = 6 I,
  radius = 3,
  z0 = 0
  },
 ComplexContourPlot[
  Abs[z - center] == radius,
  {z, -10 - 10*I, 10 + 10*I},
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Abs[z - center] == radius,
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium,
    {Point[#], InfiniteLine[{ReIm@z0, #}]} & /@
     ReIm@ SolveValues[{Abs[z - center] == radius, 
        Re[(z - center)/(z - z0)] == 0}, z]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Here's another way to compute tangency that works for equations like the one in the OP whose sides are real-valued and defined in terms of a complex `z` and functions that `ComplexExpand` will handle:

```
With[{
  z1 = 6 I,
  f1 = 3,
  z0 = 0,
  a = -5 (1 + I),
  b = 5 (1 + I)
  },
 With[{
   realeqn = Abs[z - z1] - Im[z^3] + 2 Re[z^2] == f1
   },
  ComplexContourPlot[
   realeqn, {z, a, b},
   GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> realeqn,
   Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick,
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point[ReIm@z0], 
     {Point[#], InfiniteLine[{ReIm@z0, #}]} & /@
       ReIm@NSolveValues[
        Append[            (* appends domain restrictions *)
         NestList[         (* {eqn, Dt@eqn} *)
            Dt,
            ComplexExpand[ (* convert to z, Conjugate[z] *)
             realeqn,
             z,
             TargetFunctions -> Conjugate],
            1] /.          (* rewrite Conjugate'[z] *)
           Conjugate'[z] :> Conjugate[Dt[z]]/Dt[z] /.
          {Dt[z] -> (z - z0)}, (* z lies on TL through z0 *)
         Re[a] <= Re[z] <= Re[b] && Im[a] <= Im[z] <= Im[b]
         ],
        z]}]
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add `Point[ReIm@z0]` to the `Epilog`.

Comment: @ Michael E2  quote : "Here's another way to compute tangency that works for equations like the one in the OP.." 
Can you elaborate on your idea of handling it this way ?
I don't see an intersection value yet.
I think i do see a sort of general approach ...for the absolute value equation

Comment: Interesting that this code of yours with an absolute equation, for different values yield curves to which tangents are drawn.
To calculate the intersection points of the tangents that is another story

Comment: @janhardo `NSolveValues` solves for the points of tangency by solving the system `{eqn == 0, Dt[eqn] == 0}` where `eqn` is first rewritten in terms of $z$ and its conjugate $\overline z$, and we take $d\overline z = \overline{dz}$ via `Conjugate'[z] :> Conjugate[Dt[z]]/Dt[z]` and $dz$ (= `Dt[z]`) is given by the change in $z$ along the desired tangent line via `Dt[z] -> (z - z0)`. (For the circle in the first code, it's just geometry. Two complex-plane displacements $\Delta a,\ \Delta b$ are perpendicular if $\text{Re}(\Delta a/\Delta b) = 0$.)

Comment: You can wrap `NSolveValues[..]` in parentheses and save the points of tangency inside the contour plot function, like this: `(tangentpts = NSolveValues[...])`

Comment: It is not Solve or NSolve , but NSolveValues which gives the intersections.
SolveValues then is for complex numbers.

Comment: @janhardo You could use any of `Solve`, `NSolve`, `SolveValues` or `NSolveValues` -- all will give usable solutions in complex numbers. I prefer `NSolve` since in plotting machine-real approximations are good enough; further, since I wanted just the values of the solutions, `NSolveValues` was more convenient. Use `Solve` for exact solutions if you want them, although for complicated equations expect `Root[]` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Let us call the parametric description of the circle:

```
circ[ph_] := 6 I + 3 Exp[I ph]
```

The derivative of circ is a tangent Further, the line from the origine to the circle point, where the tangent touches, is a multiple of the derivative.

Therefore, a circle-tangent point plus a multiple of the tangent must give the origin (0). We may then write:

```
circ'[ph] lam + circ[ph] == 0
```

Note further that lam and ph are real and we solve:

```
Reduce[{circ'[ph] lam + circ[ph] == 0, {  ph, lam} \[Element] 
   Reals}, { ph, lam}]
```

[image]

The information: ph= -Pi 5/6 and -Pi/6 is all we need to draw a graphics:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[circ[ph]], {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 0}, ReIm[circ[-Pi 5/6]]}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, ReIm@circ[-Pi/6]}], 
   Point[{ReIm@circ[-Pi 5/6], ReIm@circ[-Pi/6]}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 9}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Daniel Huber  thanks,  got here a value for a tangent point
Got here three other methods of solving this and all three are not yet clear for me.
Also your solution must be studied further..